# Where to find questions that are being closed on other sites, but would be on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I often randomly find questions (on StackOverflow, Statistics, etc) that are getting closed because they ask for data.

Since we [lack questions](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51674/open-data), we should monitor these channels and educate askers about our site. After some time, the moderators and active users would get the idea and start doing the same.

Example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988760/is-there-a-free-database-or-web-service-api-for-music-information-albums-artis

So, what tags on what sites should we watch?
Please answer with clickable URLs that lead directly to the search, if possible.

Comment: I've found several good candidates on stackoverflow, however those questions were closed as ``out of  topic`` are often marked as too old to be migrated ... I can't provide an example because I didn't keep track of the link

Answer (score 1):

I have added this phrase:

> If your question is not closely related to programming, please consider asking your question on https://opendata.stackexchange.com.

to the excerpts of the following tags on Stack Overflow:

- [opendata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opendata)
- [dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataset)
- [corpus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corpus)
- [wikidata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wikidata)
- [dbpedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbpedia)
- [ckan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ckan)
- [dkan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dkan)
- [socrata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/socrata)

One could flag an appropriate question, then select "in need of moderator intervention", then type something like "should be migrated to opendata.stackexchange.com".

---

BTW, more than 35% of our tags have their "counterparts" on Stack Overflow. These tags are:

> accelerometer, analysis, api, astronomy, audio, authenticity, bank,
>   bittorrent, calendar, categories, census, city, ckan, classification,
>   crowdsourcing, csv, data.gov, database, dbpedia, demographics,
>   dictionary, documentation, doi, download, economics, edgar, email,
>   energy, environment, excel, fasttext, finance, french, genome,
>   geocoding, geospatial, github, global, hadoop, html, irs, japanese,
>   json, kml, licensing, linked-data, longitudinal, machine-learning,
>   mapping, maps, media, medical, metadata, migration, mooc, music,
>   names, nlp, noaa, normalization, odata, ontology, openrefine,
>   openstreetmap, parking, parsing, pdf, photos, polling, population,
>   postal-code, privacy, products, publishing, pubmed, python, r, rdf,
>   real-time, reliability, rest, search-engine, security,
>   sentiment-analysis, shopping, social-media, socrata, space, sparql,
>   sql, standards, state, survey, text, time-series, traffic,
>   translation, trust, untagged, visualization, weather, wikidata,
>   wikimedia-commons, wikipedia, wiktionary, wkt, word2vec, wordnet, xml

Comment: Using their tags is a great idea, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Data requests on GIS (Geographic Information Systems) SE are tagged with `data`

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data

The `data` tag description says:

> Questions seeking data (except commercial) recommendations are usually
>   better asked at the Open Data Stack Exchange
>
> http://opendata.stackexchange.com
>
> Any collection of related facts arranged in a particular format;
>   often, the basic elements of information that are produced, stored, or
>   processed by a computer.
>
> The tag is designed to use for questions seeking commercial GIS data.
>
> If you seek Open Data then your question should be posted on the Open
>   Data Stack Exchange instead. That Stack Exchange has tags that include
>   geospatial, gis, maps and openstreetmap.

Answer (score 0):

Cross Validated:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=free+dataset+is%3Aquestion

StackOverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[open-source]+is%3Aquestion

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=free+dataset+is%3Aquestion

Comment: http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-request?sort=unanswered&pageSize=15